# Is only icon & title change is sufficient for putting new version of the app on app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I have searched over google for the specific rules for creating new version of an existing application but don't able to get proper rules.

I would specifically like to know that only icon and the title change of the application is enough for placing new version of the application on app store?

& if yes then. What precautions I must have take?

**UPDATE 1**

Thanks for your quick reply, Currently I'm doing the same process :) actually I know the process of creating new version but my specific concern is only icon & title change is sufficient for putting new version of the app on app store ?

**Update 2**

I have done all the changes and uploaded the binary but after uploading the status is "Invalid Binary".
Now what to do??

Comment: You don't need to chance the title or the icon. What do you need?

Comment: go to itune and clik on on ur app and you will find add new version for app

Comment: No what I need is to change the icon of the application and the name of the application as it is the only change I need to do.

Comment: Put new change and add in version update detail.  **improved minor bug**

Comment: does it required to add new version as my app is already in state of ready for sale

Comment: You will also have to increase the version number of the app (at list the minor part) - in the `-Info.plist` - and yes, it will go trough review again. You might want to tell this to the reviewer in notes field - but I doubt it will help you to get trough a review faster.

Comment: Yes, you have to upload new version for that.

Comment: yes u can do this when click on new version and u can change metadata with screenshot and icon.Note this can done only before taping on submit binary on itune

Comment: ok thanks for your quick reply :) i will do that and yes will change the version in plist file :)

Comment: sure @hfossli i will do it for sure :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a new version of an app when the current version’s status is “Ready for Sale” or Developer Removed From Sale. The new app version goes through the same review process as the first version. You have to increment your version from previous (for this could be depend on major or miner update 1.0.1) into info list

[image: New version]

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Currently I'm doing the same process :) actually I know the process of creating new version but my specific concern is only icon & title change is sufficient for putting new version of the app on app store ?

Comment: I dont think you should change the title or icon, it will create confusion on users mind. just increase the version number and give a info about why did you update this application like, fixed blah blah bug, added this feature.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to change the version number.